# How to stay "chest out"

Tags: set-phrases

I tried Google Translate and just get    チェストアウト.   Other dictionaries do not provide any meaningful results.  This is a common phrase used in sports training.  I cannot believe there is no Japanese equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an imperative: 「胸{むね}を張{は}れ！」 or 「胸を張って！」

Name of a pose: 「胸を張るポーズ」、「胸を反{そ}らすポーズ」、「胸を突{つ}き出{だ}すポーズ」, etc.

Drop the 「ポーズ」 from the expressions above and you will have the verb phrases.